# least cost path, destination unknown

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, shortest-path

**Question**
How would one going about finding a least cost path when the destination is unknown, but the number of edges traversed is a fixed value? Is there a specific name for this problem, or for an algorithm to solve it?

Note that maybe the term "walk" is more appropriate than "path", I'm not sure.

**Explanation**
Say you have a weighted graph, and you start at vertex V1. The goal is to find a path of length N (where N is the number of edges traversed, can cross the same edge multiple times, can revisit vertices) that has the smallest cost. This process would need to be repeated for all possible starting vertices.

As an additional heuristic, consider a turn-based game where there are rooms connected by corridors. Each corridor has a cost associated with it, and your final score is lowered by an amount equal to each cost 'paid'. It takes 1 turn to traverse a corridor, and the game lasts 10 turns. You can stay in a room (self-loop), but staying put has a cost associated with it too. If you know the cost of all corridors (and for staying put in each room; i.e., you know the weighted graph), what is the optimal (highest-scoring) path to take for a 10-turn (or N-turn) game? You can revisit rooms and corridors.

**Possible Approach (likely to fail)**
I was originally thinking of using Dijkstra's algorithm to find least cost path between all pairs of vertices, and then for each starting vertex subset the LCP's of length N. However, I realized that this might not give *the* LCP of length N for a given starting vertex. For example, Dijkstra's LCP between V1 and V2 might have length < N, and Dijkstra's might have excluded an unnecessary but low-cost edge, which, if included, would have made the path length equal N.

Comment: Why not do a breadth-first but add in a check for the number of steps you want, and add those to a sorted list by cost, taking the first element?

Comment: As a short-cut: check whether there are any edges within N steps that cost less than the edges that connect to the current vertex. If there are none, go forth and back on the lowest cost edge connected to current vertex (same for self-loop). Also, you do not need to consider any paths that do not include an edge cheaper than edges connected to current vertex.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting fact that if A is the adjacency matrix and you compute A<sup>k</sup> **using addition and min in place of the usual multiply and sum** used in normal matrix multiplication, then A<sup>k</sup>[i,j] is the length of the shortest path from node i to node j with exactly k edges. Now the trick is to use repeated squaring so that  A<sup>k</sup> needs only log k matrix multiply ops.

If you need the path in addition to the minimum length, you must track where the result of each min operation came from.

For your purposes, you want the location of the min of each row of the result matrix and corresponding path.

This is a good algorithm if the graph is dense.  If it's sparse, then doing one bread-first search per node to depth k will be faster.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your suggestion, @Gene. A^n gives the number of possible routes from the row index to the column index of the resultant matrix. I think you're saying, though, that I don't even do that. Is there a name of this sum-min operation? Also, it sounds like the result would give me the distance/ cost of the path, but not the path itself (i.e., it would be hard to draw a map of the path b/c the intermediate nodes aren't listed). Interesting answer though, thanks!

Comment: @rbatt Sorry it's not the number of paths. A^n[i,j] is the shortest path with n edges from i to j. But after I wrote this I realized you don't want them all. You just want to know where in each row (i.e. the j value) where the row min appears.  For this there is almost certainly a faster algorithm. Let me think about it.